# How can I disable All DML Triggers for a database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a database that handles nearly a 100 DML triggers and for some error fixing and maintenance purposes we need to disable all these triggers temporarily.

Is there any way to disable **all DML triggers** for a single database at once?

I have gone through a lot of articles and they all have suggested either the script for disabling DDL triggers or say to disable one by one which is not a great option in this case.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: for DML trigger, you need to do it for each table. You can use a script to do that. Any concern on using script to disable / enable the trigger ?

Comment: maybe [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5853/find-all-sql-server-triggers-to-quickly-enable-or-disable/) will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We managed to get a workaround unique to our system but @ankyskywalker your link was very helpful in figuring things out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still needs this, here's a solution I made for enabling/disabling all DML triggers within a database on SQL Server:

```
USE MyDatabase;

BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @NewLine CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

    DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT 
            STRING_AGG(
                CONVERT(
                    VARCHAR(MAX), 
                    'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(TRO.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TA.name) + ' DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;' + @NewLine),
                '') 
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TR.name)
        FROM 
            sys.triggers AS TR
            INNER JOIN sys.objects AS TRO ON TR.object_id = TRO.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.objects AS TA ON TRO.parent_object_id = TA.object_id
        WHERE
            TA.type = 'U') -- U: User defined table

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
        --SELECT @DynamicSQL AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('') -- 'Print' longer than 8k characters

    COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

END CATCH
```

The use of the `STRING_AGG` makes this solution only work with SQL Server 2017+, but there are many alternatives to do the same on previous versions.

To enable all triggers, just replace the `DISABLE` with `ENABLE`.

Note that `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON DATABASE` does **not** disable DML triggers on the tables, only DDL triggers created on a database level.

Comment: Excellent, but also acts on views (with an error message).
Add Where TA.Type = 'U' after 2nd inner join

Comment: @Timores that's right. I've added the filter.